# R - Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException

Tags: sql, r, rstudio-server

Getting the following error when I run a function in my code:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate
(Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 9:61
cannot recognize input near ';' '< EOF >' '< EOF >' in expression specification)
```

I call upon the function in R using:

> dbSendUpdate(hivedb,functionName(p,y))

Which I have done previously and has worked fine. The function I call upon looks like this:

```
functionName <- function(p,y) {
query <- paste('CREATE TABLE data1_', y, ' AS
               SELECT a.*
               FROM data2 a
               INNER JOIN data1_', y, ' b
               ON a.chain = b.chain
               AND a.platform = b.platform
               WHERE a.year_month LIKE "20', y,'%%"
               AND a.platform = "', p, '"
               ORDER BY a.year_month, a.platform, a.chain;', sep = '', collapse = NULL)
return(query)}
```

It's formatted exactly like the other functions that I call upon that work, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What were the inputs you used that trigger the error?

Comment: Inputs I use are for p and y (p <- platform, y <- 2015) which I called upon earlier in the code.

Comment: Other than somewhat confusingly looking for `a.year_month LIKE "202015%%"` (which I think is effectively the same as `a.year_month="2020215%"`). Perhaps you should be using single-quotes instead of double quotes, as in `"... WHERE a.year_month LIKE '20", y, "%%' ..."`, since I believe SQL wants string literals in single quotes.